# Swift messages(MT*)

Tags: apache-spark, swift-mt

I am looking for an option to store the swift messages(MT101) in hdfs or nonsql database. Can we use python in spark to store it in mongo DB? 
Please let me know if somebody worked on a similair requirement

Comment: If python is not requirement, here is how you would do it on IBM Bluemix to connect to Mongodb Lab using Scala.
https://github.com/charles2588/bluemixsparknotebooks/blob/master/mongodb_sparkConnection.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use Java in your solution, this model in the Prowide Core library is intended for MT persistence. The message is stored in raw format with metadata:

https://static.javadoc.io/com.prowidesoftware/pw-swift-core/SRU2017-7.9.7/com/prowidesoftware/swift/model/MtSwiftMessage.html

It is intended for JPA in relational databases but you could work around it to have a similar structure in Mongo DB.